# Is there a difference between "on condition that" and "provided that"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Do the terms "provided that" and "on condition that" mean the same? Or is there any difference in usage?

The means will be available provided that the state will allocate its part of financing vs. The means will be available on condition that the state will allocate its part of financing.

Comment: Just wondering: are you both *seagull*s (original poster and editor)? If you've created two accounts by mistake, [here's a link](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to help with merging them.

Comment: Lest there be any doubt, these days *provided that* is more likely to take the indicative, whereas *on condition that* is one of those few constructions in which the old present subjunctive can sometimes be heard—or more likely, read.

Comment: Is "on condition that" standard? I'd've expected "on the condition that".

Comment: For me the difference is between something over which the beneficiary has control and something over which they have none. For example "I'll give you a lift _on condition that_ you don't bring your smelly dog" is an example of something over which the beneficiary has control whereas "I'll give you a lift _provided that_ my car will start" is an example of something over which they have none.

Comment: @Lawrence: thanx for the hint about merging!

Comment: @seagull You're welcome. Glad you stayed! If you haven't already, check out ELU's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage).

Comment: @seagull Thanks for letting me know. I hope to see you around on other questions. To me, it's the *people* that matter most on sites like this. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

**provided that** has a connotation of ***assuming*** that this holds true

**on condition that** has a connotation of ***only*** if this holds true

These Ngrams show that "provided that" is more popular than "on condition that", but when we add the qualifier of ***only***, then "on condition that" becomes more popular.

[provided that, on condition that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provided+that%2Con+condition+that&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprovided%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20condition%20that%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

[only provided that,only on condition that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=only+provided+that%2Conly+on+condition+that&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conly%20provided%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conly%20on%20condition%20that%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

The Corpus of Historical American English shows similar results, with *only provided that* showing up 7 times, and *only on condition that* showing up 112 times.

[image]

The Corpus of Contemporary American English shows 4 instances vs. 23 instances.

---

As an example:

*You will be payed the bonus provided that the job is completed on time.*

*You will be payed the bonus on condition that the job is completed on time.*

The former leaves open the possibility that some other method will allow the worker to get his bonus, but the latter suggests that **ONLY** can the worker receive his bonus if he completes his job on time.

Comment: -1 Please substantiate the final paragraph: to me there is no implication in either sentence of the type you suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure how the Ngrams show meaning or correctness, so it isn't clear how they actually support the answer.  However, the explanation in the answer is correct.  @TrevorD, is your issue that you believe the explanation to be wrong, or are you looking for better supporting evidence?

Comment: @fixer1234 As my comment said, I was referring only to the 'example' at the end.  As a Brit, I do not interpret the two examples as having any difference between them. I read both as ambiguous on the possibility of other ways of receiving the bonus: I would assume (for both) that completing the job on time WILL give a bonus, but neither necessarily *excludes* other ways of getting the bonus, nor implies that there are other ways of getting it.  If I wanted expressly to exclude other ways of getting the bonus, I would put "only" in *both* sentences.

Answer (score 0):

The two conditionals are sometimes confused and used interchangeably, but remain somewhat different.

"**Provided that**" implies maintaining, introducing, or removing some tangible or quantifiable object or arrangement.

"**On condition that**" implies a set of instructions, intended to promote or prevent some event or action that might never occur.

> The means will be available *provided that* the state will allocate its
>   part of financing

Here 'provided' suggests that those means might never even *exist* if the state does nothing.

> The means will be available *on condition that* the state will allocate
>   its part of financing.

'Condition' here implies the means do exist, (they may not be *available*, but they *exist*), whatever the state may do.

Comment: How do you justify this distinction? I don't see why *on condition that* implies the existence of the means when *provided that* doesn't. (If your answer is based on dictionary definitions or on other resources, please link to them.)

Comment: @Lawrence, swap out "_the state will..._" with "_it doesn't rain._", and note how "_on condition that_" no longer quite fits.  On how that works, the OP didn't ask, so I neglected to [_provide_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=provide) for that [_condition_](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=condition).

Comment: Maybe the answer should include what's the difference between the above two usages, and "The means will be available_if_ the state allocates its part of financing.", or "Y happens _if_ X happens" and build up from that, i.e. "Y happens _provided that_ X happens", vs. "Y happens _on the condition that_ X happens".

Comment: Even with the substitution, both versions still work. Also, despite reading the etymology links, it still doesn't explain your claim that 'condition' implies the means exist while 'provided' doesn't.

Comment: @Lawrence, Re substitution:  unless at least one of the parties can control weather, "The means will be available on condition that it doesn't rain." is a malapropism; _provided that_ is vaguely religious but not incorrect, _on the contingency that_ is more neutral and most correct.